# Get requesting domain name in web service

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a web service lets say it is deployed on http://servicedomain.com/myservice.asmx. I want to call this from my another application suppose this application is deployed on http://appdomain.com/default.aspx. Now I want to get the requesting domain name in my web service file (myservice.asmx.cs) like in this case requesting domain name will be appdomain.com

Please suggest

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is to ask for the request user host name:

```
this.Request.UserHostName
```

If for some reason the DNS resolving of requestor IP is not possible, all you can get is

```
this.Request.UserHostAddress
```

which is the IP of the requestor.